# Какие есть способы эмуляции действия пользователя на чужом сайте с помощью яп?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, selenium

Например авторизацию в вк можно написать на curl. Проводим авторизацию ручками и смотрим какие запросы посылает браузер для авторизации. Повторяем их с помощ curl и все замечательно. Проблема заключается в том, что в примере с вк, все параметры можно спарсить с самой страницы, а что делать в том случае, когда параметры запросов генерируются какой-то внутренней логикой сайта?

Допустим, при нажатии на кнопку "авторизация" происходит какая то внутренняя логика, которая создает определенные ключи аутентификации, отправляет их на сервер и происходит авторизация. Спарсить этот ключ заранее нет возможности, а как узнать логику, по которой они создаются, я не знаю.

Из решений я нашел только использовать selenium, headless браузеры и подобное. Но проблема в том, что они очень медленные, а мне очень важна скорость.

Какие есть способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: «как узнать логику, по которой они создаются» — почитать код сайта (но это может оказаться долго и сложно)

Comment: @andreymal разве у меня есть доступ ко всему коду бэкенда для того чтоб посмотреть логику? (не разбираюсь)

Comment: Если они генерируются на бэкенде, значит их с бэкенда запрашивает фронтенд — и значит вы можете посмотреть код запроса и точно так же через curl запросить у бэкенда ключи. Если они генерируются на фронтенде — значит вы можете посмотреть код генерации в этом самом фронтенде.

Comment: @andreymal получается, если логика генерирования ключей происходит на фронтенде, (например в какой то функции js) то у меня есть возможность через дебаг браузера собственно посмотреть исходный код функции?

Comment: Да, если вы сможете найти эту функцию среди тонны кода

Comment: Самый простой вариант "эмуляции браузера" и автоматизации подобных действий - использование headless браузеров. Например, [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).

Comment: @nörbörnën а какие есть варианты сложнее?

Comment: @Qada поясните ваш вопрос